# Fetch Git branch in DevOps Server 2020 to build in DevOps Services Pipeline?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server, azure-devops-server-2020, azure-devops-services

We have an on-prem instance of DevOps Server 2020 hosting a Git repo as well as other ADO tools and I am doing some experimentation on a free DevOps Services instance to prevent any muddying of our existing Pipelines and Releases. I am currently stuck on the Pipeline trying to fetch a Git branch from our on-prem Git repo.

I've done quite a bit of digging already on the error code 128 with message "fatal: Authentication failed" and the DevOps Server IIS is configured with Anonymous Auth enabled and other auth options disabled. I am currently using the "Other Git" service connection option for the Pipeline source with our /tfs/ URL and provided the Pipeline with credentials to access the Git repo.

I have tested the very same URL using a `git clone` command from Git bash and it works fine, so I'm wondering why Pipelines is failing to make the connection, but I can do so fine from the command-line.

Comment: I snipped the [tag:git] tag, as Git itself does not do any authentication. Any issues you're having with authentication are from something outside Git.

Comment: A couple of questions. 

1. What kind of agent are you using to run the job? microsoft hosted or privately hosted?
2. Is your on-prem TFS sever visible to the public internet?
3. What kind of certificate do you have for your on-prem TFS server? Self-signed? Signed by your company's Certificate Authority? or signed by a well-known, public Certificate Authority?

Comment: 1. I am using an MS-hosted agent for the Pipeline. 2. It should be since it doesn't require IP whitelisting but does require a port be specified for access. 3. Cert is from a CA called GlobalSign.